# Can I perform this task without using two loops?

Tags: python, python-3.x, time-complexity

I was trying to solve a simple problem, what I have to achieve is this,
If value of `n` is `2`, then print

```
2211
21
```

or if value of `n` is `3`, print

```
333222111
332211
321
```

What i have coded is this,

```
n=3
for i in range(n,0,-1):
    for j in range(n,0,-1):
        print(str(j)*i,sep='',end='')
    print()
```

is there any way to perform this task without the two loops?

Or, can I iterate the value of `j` from `n` to `0`, without the use of a loop, and print each variation?

Comment: You are producing N lines, containing O(N) characters each - any conceivable solution is going to be at least O(N**2) just due to the amount of output.  You could write one or both iterations with recursion instead of a loop, but that's not "better" in any way, and isn't really a natural way of doing things in Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn't really a way to do this with one loop, since the task involves a double loop, but you can make it more efficient, eg use a list comprehension to build each line so you only call `print` once per line.

You *could* use recursion, but that's less efficient, and it doesn't really eliminate the loop, it just implements it in a different way.

Here's a list comp version of your code, wrapped in a function.

```
def show_pattern(n):
    for i in range(n, 0, -1):
        print(''.join([str(j)*i for j in range(n, 0, -1)]))
```

---

FWIW, here's a one-liner version that's marginally more efficient, but of course the time complexity is still O(n²). And I think you'll agree that it's a bit harder to read. ;)

```
print('\n'.join([''.join([str(j)*i for j in range(n, 0, -1)]) for i in range(n, 0, -1)]))
```

One could argue that the complexity is actually O(n³), since `str(j)*i` is performed internally by a loop, but that loop runs at C speed, so we can pretend that it's a primitive operation.

Comment: So this calls print only once, but technically it is a double loop, what would be the complexity in this case?

Comment: @loksoni Well, it calls `print` once per line. We could condense it into a single line, with one `print` in total, but either way it's still O(n**2).

Comment: time complexity O(n^2) is not directly means double loop.

Comment: @kelalaka We have a pair of nested range(n) loops. How is that *not* O(n²)?

Comment: @PM2Ring full double loop =>  O(n²), but the reverse is not always true, right? For example; if one can find a stream generator that output this sequence where will be the double loop?

Comment: @kelalaka Indeed, the reverse is not always true, but I haven't said anything here which implies that.

Comment: @PM2Ring I did'nt say it for anybody. Just to make clear. one up for your comment was from me..

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with recursion, but the time complexity wont change... Something like this:

```
def method(n, size):
    if n == 0:
        return;
    for i in range(size,0,-1):
        print(str(i)*n,sep='',end='')
    print()
    method(n-1, size)

method(3, 3)
```